# how to unprotect a excel file manual (by doing it myself) when password is known

Tags: excel, ms-office, password-protection

I have a big excel sheet with multiple sub-sheets in it and formulas and filters. I protected the file with a password about one year ago. Now there seems no necessity any longer to have a password on it. I manually protected the file with my excel options and now I was about to unprotect it one year later.
But I realized that I do not know how to do this on that file, even if the password is known. The following things I have tried already:

-"Save as", but the password seems to be kept on every copy I save for new

- Copy and paste in empty document (all formulas, filters, tables, sub-sheets, formats etc.) are gone after that - no option, even if it would work for just keeping the text.
- Reading the Excel help and followed the suggestions. All options that were suggested are greyed out on that particular file. On a new file I can do that, but on this one not. I have all permissions and I am the owner of the file.
  The sheet seems not to be separate protected or the tool to unprotect the sheet is also greyed out. I copied the file on my Desktop and retried, but there are still all options to unprotect the file greyed out. I am local admin on my computer. The file is not corrupted. I have no idea what could it be else.

What else can I do? I just need to remove the password prompt from that file!
I do not do any programming work or scripts, so please do not misunderstand me.

Comment: I thought you could just open in openoffice ans save as xls or break into the .zip and delete a file.

Comment: @Jeeped Numbers happily opens excel password protection and gets rid of it - well did last time I tried... 2 months ago...